# Sending post details is also sending my submit/post

Tags: javascript, php, html

How will i send a post without submitting my submit also? 
As i've tried posting with this code, the submit or the POST is combining with my post details. Please help, thank you

```html
<form id="myForm" action="sample.com" method="POST">
    <tbody>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Amount:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount" value="100.00"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Currency:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="currency" value="PHP"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Customer email:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer_email" name="customer_email" value="test123@gmail.com"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Customer name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer_name" name="customer_name" value="Pedro Pen duko"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Service ID:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="service_id" value="HDSQ00011"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Customer ID:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer_id" value="cust_121"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Order Number:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="order_no" name="order_no" value="12312"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product Description:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_description" value="321"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Remarks:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="remarks" value="12321"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Transaction timestamp:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="transaction_time" value="2018-10-08 14:08:00"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">POST</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </tbody>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you seem to have the button setup incorrectly, simply change the following line:

```
<button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">POST</button>
```

to something like this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">POST</button>
```

The change the `name="submit"` to `type="submit"`.

This should fix your code to send the post request, another fix could be with JQuery, however, this is just avoiding the issue rather than properly fixing it, here is how you could do this in Jquery:

```
$("name='submit'").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

The code above will add a listener for when the user clicks on the button, this would mean that you could leave your HTML code and just add this to your JavaScript as long as you have [jquery](https://code.jquery.com/) loaded.

Comment: Will try this thank you! Would you mind to share your another fix with JQuery?

Comment: @Julius Using Jquery wouldn't be ideal, however, I'll add it to the answer shortly.

Comment: that would be a great help on my knowledge. Thank you

Comment: @Julius I've added the JQuery code that should work for your HTML code.

Comment: hello if i change the name into type, how will i get the trigger for the button w/o declaring the name? 
ps: is it okay to ask more questions in here?

Comment: @Julius If you change the type to submit then the form will be submitted via POST.

Comment: Got it got it, already fixed my problem thank you so much flux! Savior of the day ^_^

Comment: Hi Flux, i need your help again. Is there anyway for a php function to call without using the name attribute of the button? I can only use the id attribute, not the name. Thank you

Comment: With JQuery you can just use `$("#id")` learn more @ https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Answer (score -1):

**Html Code:**

```
<form id="myForm" action="sample.com" method="POST">
</form>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit(function () {
        var formInput = $(this).serialize();

    $.post( 'some-url', formInput, function(data) {
         ... do something with response from server
       },
       'json' // I expect a JSON response
    );
    }); 
});
```